# Build Python (2.7) module on GCC 4.8 fails

Tags: c, gcc, python-2.7, compilation

I'm trying to build a Python Module/extension write using C API, but it fails:

```
% python2 cmath.py build
running build
running build_ext
building 'c_math' extension
creating build
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -DNDEBUG -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c c_math.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/c_math.o
c_math.c:18:5: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
 {"more", c_math_more, METH_VARARGS, "n + nn Using C API"},
 ^
c_math.c:18:5: warning: (near initialization for ‘c_mathMethods[0].ml_meth’) [enabled by default]
In file included from /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:58:0,
             from c_math.c:1:
/usr/include/python2.7/pyport.h:802:39: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘void’
 #               define PyMODINIT_FUNC void
                                   ^
c_math.c:22:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘PyMODINIT_FUNC’
 PyMODINIT_FUNC
 ^
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I've tried to build manually without distutils but i get same error/warnings messages

c_math.c:

```
#include <Python.h>

static PyObject *
c_math_more(PyObject *self, PyObject *n, PyObject *nn) {
    if ( PyInt_Check(n) && PyInt_Check(nn) ) {
        float cn, cnn, result;

        cn = PyInt_AsLong(n);
        cnn = PyInt_AsLong(nn);

        result = cn + cnn;

        return PyInt_FromLong(result);
    }
}

static PyMethodDef c_mathMethods[] = {
    {"more", c_math_more, METH_VARARGS, "n + nn Using C API"},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
}

PyMODINIT_FUNC
initc_math() {
    (void) Py_InitModule("c_math", c_mathMethods);
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);

    Py_Initialize();

    initc_math();
}
```

And cmath.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

c_math = Extension('c_math', sources = ['c_math.c'])

setup(name = 'c_math',
      version = '1.0',
      description = "c_math setup",
      ext_modules = [c_math])
```

What i'm doing incorrect ?

ps: please, if exists other errors on c_math.c (i mean errors that isn't showed by gcc) DON'T talk me, I want to find the errors by myself ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  static PyMethodDef c_mathMethods[] = {
      {"more", c_math_more, METH_VARARGS, "n + nn Using C API"},
      {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
- }
+ };
```

You are missing a semicolon at the end...

Comment: Thanks, after this compile... i've more one question, and the warning "warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]" how to fix this ? and also "warning: (near initialization for ‘c_mathMethods[0].ml_meth’) [enabled by default]"