# Why am I getting this error when building the python module?

Tags: python, c, python-2.7

I am currently working on building a python module in C. I have followed a tutorial series to get my self to a building point, and I have a pretty good grasp of what is going on.

However, when I run the script to set everything up I have the following printout. Looks like the error is coming from one of the header files in python-dev; however, I wanted to reach out here to make sure it isn't something I am doing. I am going to include the error code, and I can provide the other files on request.

```
sudo python setup.py build
running build
running build_ext
building 'lidar' extension
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c lidar_module.c -o build/temp.linux-armv6l-2.7/lidar_module.o
lidar_module.c: In function ‘lidar_test’:
lidar_module.c:8:6: warning: unused variable ‘sts’ [-Wunused-variable]
  int sts = 0;
      ^
In file included from /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:58:0,
                 from lidar_module.c:1:
lidar_module.c: At top level:
/usr/include/python2.7/pyport.h:802:39: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘void’
 #               define PyMODINIT_FUNC void
                                       ^
lidar_module.c:24:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘PyMODINIT_FUNC’
 PyMODINIT_FUNC initlidar(){
 ^
lidar_module.c:3:18: warning: ‘lidarError’ defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
 static PyObject *lidarError;
                  ^
lidar_module.c:19:20: warning: ‘lidar_methods’ defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
 static PyMethodDef lidar_methods[] = {
                    ^
error: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I peeked into the header file and found this around the area of the error.

```
#ifndef PyMODINIT_FUNC
#       if defined(__cplusplus)
#               fndef PyMODINIT_FUNC
#       if defined(__cplusplus)
#               define PyMODINIT_FUNC extern "C" void
#       else /* __cplusplus */
#               define PyMODINIT_FUNC void
#       endif /* __cplusplus */
#endif
```

Answer (score -1):

I literally had to search the line number output from the console, but I did find the solution here:
[Build Python (2.7) module on GCC 4.8 fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16181628/build-python-2-7-module-on-gcc-4-8-fails)

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged. Mark it a duplicate instead.